# socat bidrectionally with a shell script. echo, read, then hand off to socat

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, socket, socat, unix-sockets

There is a VMM which doesn't conform to the the standard VSOCK implementation: Firecracker

For each guest it creates a v.sock unix socket file

The ordinary VSOCK-CONNECT:cid:1234 then becomes:

```
UNIX-CONNECT:/path/to/v.sock -
CONNECT 1234
OK 1234567890
```

At which point the VMM establishes a connection to VSOCK-LISTEN:1234 on the guest and drops you into it.

On the guest:

```
socat VSOCK-LISTEN:1234,reuseaddr,fork exec:'/bin/bash -li',pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane
```

What I have tried that didn't work at all:

/vbin/fireshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'CONNECT 1234'
read
exec socat - file:`tty`,rawer
```

Then on the host:

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/srv/firecracker/test/root/v.sock exec:/vbin/fireshell
```

But it doesn't work and the error makes no sense:

```
socat[7110] E exactly 2 addresses required (there are 4); use option "-h" for help
```

I'm at a loss what to do to get an adequate solution, the following did work but it also polluted the shell to some extent and created an undesirable socket:

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/srv/firecracker/test/root/v.sock,end-close UNIX-LISTEN:/vbin/shell.sock,reuseaddr,fork
```

Then

```
socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/vbin/shell.sock
CONNECT 1234
OK 1073741841
bash-5.1# ^C
```

And only afterward I can get the shell I want, albeit somewhat polluted, but seems to work once you ctrl+c or enter in it once.

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/vbin/shell.sock file:`tty`,rawer
```

Surely there is some way to do it with socat cleanly without having to code and compile a solution?

Comment: Use `expect`. Read `man expect`.